# React Native, having problems with Flex Box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I'm practicing my React Native programming and I have an issue with the Flex Layout that I don't seem to understand pretty well

I wanted to make my test app look like this image below

[Sample App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3n5jz.png)

But in the end, this is what I get. There is some misalignment in the 'Home' text which suppose to be centered properly and a missing gap on the two right icons.

[Sample Test App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXMqd.png)

I have tried putting padding on the two icon but have no luck with in.

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
          <View style={styles.headerBrandingContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.headerBranding}>Brand</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.headerRowContainer}>
            <Icon name="menu" size={30} color="white" />
            <Text style={styles.headerRowPage}>Home</Text>
            <View style={styles.headerRowIcons}>
              <Icon name="filter" size={30} color="white" />
              <Icon name="search" size={30} color="white" />
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',

  },
  headerContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#3498db',
    height: 180,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  headerBrandingContainer: {
    marginTop: 50,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  headerBranding: {
    fontSize: 40,
    fontWeight: '400',
    letterSpacing: 1,
    color: '#fff',
  },
  headerRowContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    margin: 10
  },
  headerRowIcons: {
    //backgroundColor: 'red',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  headerRowPage: {
    // marginLeft:20,
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: '500',
    color: '#fff',

  }
});
```

Comment: try `flex:1` for `headerRowIcons`

Comment: @AravindS tried flex:1 on headerRowIcons and it will push everything all the way to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To align childs of headerContainer vertically you should use alignItems with the code below :

```
headerContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    backgroundColor: '#3498db',
    height: 180,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
}
```

A usefull resource to understand flexbox : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Remove too your marginTop on headerBrandingContainer styles.

EDIT:

Finally I think the best way is to make some modifications in the component tree so that the headerRowContainer items are all flex elements to 1. In this way, the title is always centered (the views having the same size) and we can now manage the placement of buttons without impacting the rest. It works perfectly for me.

```
import React from 'react';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
          <View style={styles.headerBrandingContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.headerBranding}>Brand</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.headerRowContainer}>
            <View style={styles.buttonsContainerLeft}>
              <Icon name="menu" size={30} color="white" />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.headerRowPage}>Home</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.headerRowIcons}>
              <Icon
                name="filter"
                size={30}
                color="white"
                style={styles.filterIcon}
              />
              <Icon name="search" size={30} color="white" />
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  headerContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#3498db',
    height: 180,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  headerBrandingContainer: {
    marginTop: 50,
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  headerBranding: {
    fontSize: 40,
    fontWeight: '400',
    letterSpacing: 1,
    color: '#fff'
  },
  headerRowContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    margin: 10
  },
  buttonsContainerLeft: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start'
  },
  titleContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  headerRowIcons: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end'
  },
  headerRowPage: {
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: '500',
    color: '#fff'
  },
  filterIcon: {
    marginRight: 20
  }
});
```

Comment: I have tried using alignItem but the everything squeeze together in the rowContainer even if i use space-between in justifyContent

Comment: And removing your marginTop in headerBrandingContainer's styles ?

Comment: Still the same without the marginTop

Comment: I tried to reproduce on codepen and i use margin-right on the filter icon to add spacing and align-items: center. The behavior seems correct : https://codepen.io/Maestro31/pen/BVGPjB

Comment: I tried follow everything in codepen but the result was totally different in React Native. This is what i get -> https://ibb.co/jbC3AT

Comment: Remove width of 400px that i have added for example

Comment: result is still the same as i what i have showed you :/

Comment: Adding flex: 1 on headerRowContainer ?

Comment: it looks great now thank you! does it work with larger screen? cause i see you manually set the margin for the filter icon

Comment: Yes because alignItems in headerRowIcons is set to flex-end. If you add icons you can just set a marginLeft to all and keep the same spacing.